# How to create a Progress Ring like Windows 8 Style in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, progress-bar

I want to show progress in my Desktop apps like Windows 8 `ProgressRing`. This type of progress is shown at times of installation or when Windows Start, but this control can be used in many applications as its very clean and modern, but I don't know how to achieve that. The progress ring image is here.

Please see the image:

[image]

May I know how do I code for it may be in XAML or in Code? I have seen that in WPF `ProgressRing` control is not present, so I have to go to some custom control. Idea link or suggestions please how can I proceed.

Comment: If you want to learn about the process, read this article: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/06/lets-code-build-custom-progress-ring-in.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `MahApps.Metro` would be much simpler, but given below is a simple Metro-like wait indicator showing how it would be done in XAML.

```
<Viewbox>
        <Canvas Width="50" Height="50"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Path Data="M50,27.5 C50,24.23333 45,24.23333 45,27.5 C45,30.83333 50,30.83333 50,27.5"
                  Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.83333">
                <Path.RenderTransform >
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot1" Angle="0"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_rot1"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="360"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase Power="1.3" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Path.Triggers>
            </Path>
            <Path Data="M50,27.5 C50,24.23333 45,24.23333 45,27.5 C45,30.83333 50,30.83333 50,27.5"
                  Fill="#DDFFFFFF"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.83333">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot2" Angle="13"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_rot2"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="13"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="13"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="-347">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase Power="1.3" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-347"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Path.Triggers>
            </Path>
            <Path Data="M50,27.5 C50,24.23333 45,24.23333 45,27.5 C45,30.83333 50,30.83333 50,27.5"
                  Fill="#BBFFFFFF"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.83333">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot3" Angle="26"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_rot3"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="26"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="26"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.4" Value="-334">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase Power="1.3" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-334"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Path.Triggers>
            </Path>

            <Path Data="M50,27.5 C50,24.23333 45,24.23333 45,27.5 C45,30.83333 50,30.83333 50,27.5"
                  Fill="#99FFFFFF"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.83333">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot4" Angle="39"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_rot4"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="39"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="39"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.6" Value="-321">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase Power="1.3" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-321"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Path.Triggers>
            </Path>
            <Path Data="M50,27.5 C50,24.23333 45,24.23333 45,27.5 C45,30.83333 50,30.83333 50,27.5"
                  Fill="#77FFFFFF"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.83333">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot5" Angle="52"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_rot5"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="52"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="52"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="-308">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase Power="1.3" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-308"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Path.Triggers>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
```

It's essentially the same `Path` object, a filled circle, used 5 times, at 5 different rotation angles and 5 different opacity values for the fill.

Doubtless, there is a more efficient way to do this, but this method shows the animation and timings, as well as the easing to give it more natural, less abrupt feel, when the circles spin around and stop.

Comment: I Think I need to use the `<ViewBox> ... </ViewBox>` inside the `Grid` control. But how do I trigger the animation? The animation does not seems to start, Do I need to write any code in xaml.cs ?

Comment: In the example, the animation triggers as soon as the Path object is loaded, which doesn't happen in design view (you have to run the window this is placed on to see the animation).  `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">`  You can trigger the animations from pretty much any event you want, either by using XAML or using code.

Comment: your example is working perfectly, but after a complete rotation it stops. Any idea why its stopping? `RepeatBehaviour` is `Forever` but still it stops. after a rotation of 270 degree.

Comment: Not sure why it would be stopping.  On my screen the lead circle rotates 360 deg in 2 seconds, then pauses for 1 second, while the others catch up.    Then repeats forever.

Comment: Works great for me, thanks for your work on making this control.

Comment: This is great! My OCD can't go past the fact that it doesn't lead to perfect circles though, they look a bit oval in shape.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`ProgressRing`](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/controls/progress-ring.html) from `MahApps.Metro`:

> The `ProgressRing` control is styled after a similar control in Windows 8 to indicate activity rather than a percentage of progress completed.

Example:

```
<Controls:ProgressRing IsActive="True" />
```

To change the size of the rings, you need to set `Width` and `Height`. Also, you can set a different color for each ring and set the size less than the established. To do this and get this Control without install full `MahApps.Metro` pack, look at my previous answer:

[Make the ProgressRing in MahApps.Metro Smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774185/make-the-progressring-in-mahapps-metro-smaller)

Comment: I believe that MahApps.Metro is not free. There may be some licensing issue, any ideas how to achieve that in code?

Comment: @Debhere: As far as I know it's free. If you want get this control without install, see my example in answer, it has a reference to the project.

Comment: MahApps.Metro is free!